# SVN commit on windows XP

Tags: linux, tortoisesvn, fedora12

I have svn sever on Fedora 12. If I commit to repo from linux machine, if I commit from my MAC laptop all is ok, however when I try to commit from my windows XP laptop png files will not commit, every other file type works on the windows laptop. This is obviously something to do with windows, but I haven't got a clue what!!!!

I have been trying to resolve this for over a week now but with no success.

Error Msg is;

"Could not read status line; An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: This might be a firewall issue. If you're on your local network, try disconnecting from the internet, turning off your personal firewall and committing. It might also be a firewall setting on the Linux end?

Comment: If it's a firewall issue, why would all the other file types work. I have openvpn working and the MAC laptop can commit png files from work. The windows laptop is on my LAN but will commit every file type except PNG files

Comment: Oh I overread that part, sorry. I retract my comment. :)

Comment: Does this also occur with a totally fresh repository? Does it also occur with random PNGs downloaded from the Internet?

Comment: Yes I have created a new repository and it still fails, I am trying to commit drupal themes

Comment: Very, very odd. The only idea to try that comes to mind is re-installing the local SVN client. Sorry...

Comment: OK thanks, have tried that and also tried to use rapid svn, but still get exactly the same issue, but thanks for the input

Comment: It might still be worth trying deactivating the personal firewall and/or virus scanner. Maybe a virus scanner chokes on some signature typical for PNG files and terminates the connection or something.

Comment: Can you check wether the svn:mime-type property is set, and to what value? `svn propget svn:mime-type <FILE>`

Comment: svn:mime-type is set to image/png

Answer (score 1):

Disable your virus scanner. Some of them check network traffic and falsely find 'dangerous' content even in images. They then 'sanitize' that network data packets (i.e., they change it!) and Subversion detects that the data doesn't match anymore.

Comment: Thanks Stefan and Pekka, it seems that only MacAfee is the issue, if I disable it everythign works OK, I have another machine with Norton Antivirus and that works fine with Antivirus enabled.